# Issue with configuring internet gateway on Debian server

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox

VM2 connected to internet gateway (VM1) cannot access internet (VirtualBox)

I have installed VirtualBox VMs on my Linux (Ubuntu) which has wired internet connection. I want to connect my VM2 (Server linux) to internet through a VM1 (Gate Linux), I tried multiple approaches, please see the attached picture, but still no luck VM2 still cannot access internet via Gate Linux, when I am running traceroute from Server Linux its outputs that most of the internet requests stop on Gate Linux. Can you please assist me with configuring internet Gate Linux in virtualbox enviroment.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYSnM.png)

Comment: Can you ping (gateway) 192.168.13.1 from VM2? Also you don't need ip_forward rule on vm2.

Comment: yes I can ping from VM2 -> VM1 machine.

Comment: Can you please provide complete traceroute from VM2 to 192.168.0.1?

Comment: output from VM2:
server:corp13.un:~# tracertoute 192.168.0.1

traceroute to 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
   1. proxy (192.168.13.1) 0.697 ms 0.778 ms 1.357 ms
   2. * * *
   3. * * *

Comment: Good, it looks like you can reach 192.168.0.1, but 192.168.0.1 cannot reply back as it has no idea that 192.168.0.5 has a route to 192.168.13.0/24 network. 

Try adding a static route  on your 192.168.0.1 router specifying 
192.168.0.1 as a route to 192.168.13.0/24 network.

Comment: I see, let me have a look at my home route settings, I have a very tiny experience with routers :)

Comment: Hmmm, I don't see that option add static ipv4 route on my router and via Router webconsole I can ping 192.168.13.1 (VM1) and cannot ping 192.168.13.10 (VM2)
router model is ZXHN H118N, maybe I should update the software on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you also cannot ping 192.168.13.1 from your server as it has no route to 192.168.13.0/24. By default it would send requests uplink, and of course your internet provider wouldn't know where 192.168.13.0/24 is either. 
So you will have to add a static route on 192.168.0.1, specifying 192.168.0.1 as a route to 192.168.13.0/24 network.

Маршрутизация IPv4 is what you are looking for.

Сеть -> Маршрутизация(IPv4)
[image: Концигурация Роутера РосТелеком]

Comment: but I can ping my VM1 from router:

https://ibb.co/DGcBGNr

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.13.1 from 192.168.0.1? I am pretty sure you can only ping  192.168.0.5, which is going to be in the same network as your router (192.168.0.0/24). But you need to access 192.168.13.1, which is located in a separate network (192.168.13.0/24)

Comment: ok, so you can ping 192.168.13.1, and not 192.168.13.10?

Comment: well, I definitely can ping my virtual machine from my Wi-Fi Router :)
https://ibb.co/FzmFwZ8
https://ibb.co/P5xs1nv
please see attachments.

Comment: yeah right, I can ping 192.168.13.1 (VM1) and cannot ping 192.168.13.10 (VM2) from my router

Comment: How about from 13.1 to 13.10? I am asking because it can be related to virtualbox type of the connection.  Talking about host-only.

Comment: ping between VMs works fine from both sides.

Comment: Ok, so the issue is definitely on your VM1. Either packet forwarding is not working properly or NAT needs to be configured in a proper way.

Please show the output of the following on VM1:
```cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward```

Comment: cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   1

Comment: Good, now we will need to apply NAT rules on your VM1 in case eth0 is your connection to 192.168.0.0/24 goes through eth0 and to 192.168.13.0/24 through eth1:

 ```modprobe iptable_nat \

iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE \

iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -j ACCEPT```

Comment: Something like this will work as well:

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
# iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: well, a little typo, eth0 192.168.13.0/24 and eth1 192.168.0.0/24 and command should be, right? :)
`modprobe iptable_nat \ iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE \ iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: Correct, try that and let me know. I put slash to show you that those commands needs to be issued separately, one at a time. You could use && instead of \ to put this all in one line

Comment: it seems that everything now work as expected :D
Thank you very much Dmitriy!!!

Comment: I am glad it works, now you will need to save those NAT rules, to make a permanent change on VM1. Otherwise it will break after VM1 reboots.  You can run the following command `iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf`. Make sure it works after you reboot VM1.

Comment: well after reboot it stopped working, I re-run the commands and now lab works as expected

Comment: You will need to save rules by running `sudo iptables-save', then reboot and test again. 
Or you could benefir from debian based package iptables-persistent:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/52522/320814

Comment: thank you, after saving rules in /etc/iptables/rules.v4 everything works fine :)